# How to join values using join in python

Tags: python

I am trying to build create table statement using python.

my values are stored as following

```
strsql = ('Col1'   'TEXT'
         , ' col2'   'NUMBER(38, 0)'
         , 'col3'   'TEXT'
         , 'col4'   'TEXT'
         , 'col5'   'TIMESTAMP_NTZ')
```

and using below to

```
 print(', '.join(['t.$1:' + i[0] for i in strsql]))
```

i am getting output as  *t.$1:C, t.$1:C , t.$1:c, t.$1:c, t.$1:c*

expectation: t.$1:Col1, t.$1:col2 , t.$1:col3, t.$1:col4, t.$1:col5

what I am missing in print statement!

Answer (score 1):

The inferred type of the `strsql` variable is currently a `tuple[str, ...]`.

This happens because `'Col1'   'TEXT'` actually concatenates the string into a single string value, like `i = 'Col1Text'` in this case. Thus, accessing `i[0]` of this value returns the first character in the string element, or `C` in this case.

For a simple fix, modify your `strsql` variable to be a `tuple[tuple[str, str], ...]` type instead - that is, a tuple of one or more `(name, type)` elements.

```py
strsql = (('Col1', 'TEXT'),
          (' col2', 'NUMBER(38, 0)'),
          ('col3', 'TEXT'),
          ('col4', 'TEXT'), ('col5', 'TIMESTAMP_NTZ'))
```

With this change in place, your original `print` statement now prints the desired result:

```
t.$1:Col1, t.$1: col2, t.$1:col3, t.$1:col4, t.$1:col5
```

Answer (score 0):

You access the first character of each string.
What you really want is to access the first part.

```
strsql = (('Col1', 'TEXT'), ('col2', 'NUMBER(38, 0)'), ('col3', 'TEXT'), ('col4', 'TEXT'), ('col5', 'TIMESTAMP_NTZ'))
print(', '.join(['t.$1:' + col for col, _ in strsql]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can slice the indiced index of character `i[:4]`:

```
strsql = ('Col1' 'TEXT' , 'col2' 'NUMBER(38, 0)' , 'col3' 'TEXT' , 'col4' 'TEXT' , 'col5' 'TIMESTAMP_NTZ')
print(', '.join([f"t.$1:{i[:4]}" for i in strsql]))

# t.$1:Col1, t.$1:col2, t.$1:col3, t.$1:col4, t.$1:col5
```

Comment: thanks.  how do i construct if char lengths are >4.

Comment: You could change your data structure as other answer suggested